# using setup.py to run tests that presently require pipenv

Tags: python, pytest, setup.py, pipenv

I would like my Python project to be testable with: `python setup.py test`. I am using `pipenv` and `pytest`. The reason for pipenv is to have a configuration of Python and dependent libraries that is isolated from the system-installed packages. Presently, to run the unit tests I `pipenv shell`, and then from within the shell, `pytest`. Then `exit` to exit the shell. So  now I would like to achieve the same effect with `python setup.py test`. Is there a canonical approach for this?

Comment: I can't say I understood your problem clear. Why don't you just: `pipenv run setup.py test` ?

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I didn't see the 'run' cmd...

Comment: ` run        Spawns a command installed into the virtualenv.` You can `pipenv shell` and then `[your command]` or just `pipenv run [your command]` in one line

Comment: This worked as needed: `pipenv run pytest --cov=mymodule`

Comment: Congratulations! Although I don't think it was a very good question